# jQuery.inArray(), how to use it right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time I work with `jQuery.inArray()` and it acts kinda strange.

If the object is in the array, it will return 0, but 0 is false in Javascript. So the following will output: *"is NOT in array"*

```
var myarray = [];
myarray.push("test");

if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray)) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

I will have to change the if statement to:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray)==0)
```

But this makes the code unreadable. Especially for someone who doesn't know this function. They will expect that jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) gives true when "test" is in the array.

So my question is, why is it done this way? I realy dislike this. But there must be a good reason to do it like that.

Answer (score 877, accepted):

`inArray` returns the index of the element in the array, not a boolean indicating if the item exists in the array. If the element was not found, `-1` will be returned.

So, to check if an item is in the array, use:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) !== -1)
```

Comment: CoffeeScript: `if jQuery.inArray('test', myarray) isn't -1`

Comment: Of course, you could always define your own, more intuitive, function like `$.isInArray = function(test,array) {  return $.inArray(test, array) !== -1; };`

Comment: Or shorter: `$.isInArray = function(item, array) { return !!~$.inArray(item, array); };` (I would keep cryptic code like that in a well named function to keep the intention clear though :) )

Comment: Thanks @Chips_100 for showing us visual learners how to do it right, it'd be nice if jQuery could update to include that in their own example.

Comment: @notblakeshelton You're absolutely correct. I think autocorrect snuck that apostrophe in there.

Comment: What is the need of type checking for result. no need of `!==`, only `!=` is sufficient, isn't it?

Comment: you can also use `if( $.inArray(test, array) > -1) { // do stuff }`

Comment: Here `if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) != -1)`  any **- ( negative )** number shall be placed right ! __Why everyone using -1__ ?. as @MistyDawn stated it!!

Answer (score 70):

[`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the *index* of the element if found or -1 if it isn't -- not a boolean value. So the correct is

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) != -1) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Answer (score 29):

The right way of using `inArray(x, arr)` is **not using it at all**, and using instead `arr.indexOf(x)`.

The official standard name is also more clear on the fact that the returned value is an index thus if the element passed is the first one you will get back a `0` (that is falsy in Javascript).

(Note that `arr.indexOf(x)` is **not supported in Internet Explorer until IE9**, so if you need to support IE8 and earlier, this will not work, and the jQuery function is a better alternative.)

Comment: I have to agree. The name of inArray is confusing. It seems it should return a boolean, but it does exactly the same as indexOf

Comment: Everytime I `$.inArray` used at the beginning of some code I have to go fix a bug in, I groan. Anyway, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why would you want to take your pen, drain the blue ink and fill it with red ink when you can use a red marker from the beginning

Answer (score 28):

The answer comes from the first paragraph of the documentation check if the results is greater than -1, not if it's true or false.

> The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

Answer (score 21):

instead of using `jQuery.inArray()` you can also use `includes` method for int array :

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
// expected output: true

var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(pets.includes('cat'));
// expected output: true

console.log(pets.includes('at'));
// expected output: false
```

check official post [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: includes is not supported by IE - :: use indeOf

Comment: includes is perfectly working on jquery 3.6

Answer (score 14):

The `inArray` function returns the index of the object supplied as the first argument to the function in the array supplied as the second argument to the function.

When `inArray` returns `0` it is indicating that the first argument was found at the first position of the supplied array.

To use `inArray` within an if statement use:

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) != -1) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

`inArray` returns `-1` when the first argument passed to the function is not found in the array passed as the second argument.

Answer (score 14):

Or if you want to get a bit fancy you can use the bitwise not (~) and logical not(!) operators to convert the result of the inArray function to a boolean value.

```
if(!!~jQuery.inArray("test", myarray)) {
    console.log("is in array");
} else {
    console.log("is NOT in array");
}
```

Comment: The use of bitwise operators is generally forbidden/frowned upon in the common JavaScript coding standards. So if you're using a linter (jshint, eslint etc.) chances are you won't get this through code review. Solution works though.

Answer (score 13):

**inArray** returns the index of the element in the array. If the element was not found, -1 will be returned else index of element.

```
if(jQuery.inArray("element", myarray) === -1) {
    console.log("Not exists in array");
} else {
    console.log("Exists in array");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I usually use

```
if(!(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) < 0))
```

or

```
if(jQuery.inArray("test", myarray) >= 0)
```

Comment: Even better... `if( $.inArray("test", myarray) > -1 )`

Answer (score 4):

jQuery.inArray() returns index of the item in the array, or -1 if item was not found. Read more here: [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 4):

It will return the index of the item in the array. If it's not found you will get `-1`

Answer (score 3):

If we want to check an element is inside a set of elements we can do for example:

```
var checkboxes_checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

// Whenever a checkbox or input text is changed
$('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="text"]').change(function() {
    // Checking if the element was an already checked checkbox
    if($.inArray( $(this)[0], checkboxes_checked) !== -1) {
        alert('this checkbox was already checked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.inArray()` does the **EXACT SAME THING** as `myarray.indexOf()` and returns the index of the item you are checking the array for the existence of. It's just compatible with earlier versions of IE before IE9. The best choice is probably to use `myarray.includes()` which returns a boolean true/false value. See snippet below for output examples of all 3 methods.

```js
// Declare the array and define it's values
var myarray = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'];

// Display the return value of each jQuery function 
// when a radio button is selected
$('input:radio').change( function() {

  // Get the value of the selected radio
  var selectedItem = $('input:radio[name=arrayItems]:checked').val();
  $('.item').text( selectedItem );
  
  // Calculate and display the index of the selected item
  $('#indexVal').text( myarray.indexOf(selectedItem) );
  
  // Calculate and display the $.inArray() value for the selected item
  $('#inArrVal').text( $.inArray(selectedItem, myarray) );
  
  // Calculate and display the .includes value for the selected item
  $('#includeVal').text( myarray.includes(selectedItem) );
});
```

```css
#results { line-height: 1.8em; }
#resultLabels { width: 14em; display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; float: left; }
label { margin-right: 1.5em; }
.space { margin-right: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click a radio button to display the output of
&nbsp;<code>$.inArray()</code>
&nbsp;vs. <code>myArray.indexOf()</code>
&nbsp;vs. <code>myarray.includes()</code>
&nbsp;when tested against
&nbsp;<code>myarray = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish'];</code><br><br>

<label><input type="radio" name="arrayItems" value="Cat"> Cat</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="arrayItems" value="Dog"> Dog</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="arrayItems" value="Fish"> Fish</label>  
<label><input type="radio" name="arrayItems" value="N/A"> ← Not in Array</label>
<br><br>

<div id="results">
  <strong>Results:</strong><br>
  <div id="resultLabels">
    myarray.indexOf( "<span class="item">item</span>" )<br>
    $.inArray( "<span class="item">item</span>", myarray )<br>
    myarray.includes( "<span class="item">item</span>" )
  </div>
  <div id="resultOutputs">
    <span class="space">=</span><span id="indexVal"></span><br>
    <span class="space">=</span><span id="inArrVal"></span><br>
    <span class="space">=</span><span id="includeVal"></span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It should be noted that `$.inArray` should be the golden standard if you have access to the jQuery library.  Otherwise, JavaScript `.indexOf` with a polyfill for IE8 should be used instead.  Stay away from that modern stuff like `.includes()`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var abc = {
      "partner": {
        "name": "North East & Cumbria (EDT)",
        "number": "01915008717",
        "areas": {
        "authority": ["Allerdale", "Barrow-in-Furness", "Carlisle"]
        }
      }
    };
    
    
    $.each(abc.partner.areas, function(key, val){
     console.log(val);
      if(jQuery.inArray("Carlisle", val)) {
        console.log(abc.partner.number);
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(one|two|tree)$/i.test(field) // field = Two; // true
/^(one|two|tree)$/i.test(field) // field = six; // false
/^(раз|два|три)$/ui.test(field) // field = Три; // true
```

This is useful for checking dynamic variables. This method is easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Just no one use `$` instead of `jQuery`:

```
if ($.inArray(nearest.node.name, array)>=0){
   console.log("is in array");
}else{
   console.log("is not in array");
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious why? Is there some uncommon compatibility issue this causes? I've never had any kind of issue using the `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Man, check the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

for example:

```
var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
console.log(jQuery.inArray( "John", arr ) == 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when you try to check for a jquery DOM element it won't work properly. So rewriting the function would do the trick:

```
function isObjectInArray(array,obj){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if($(obj).is(array[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var college_year = [2021,2022,2023, 2024];
var arraylen = college_year.length;
// Use an array to store the dynamic arrays
var year_arrays = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arraylen; i++) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(college_year[i], year_arrays) === -1) {
    year_arrays.push(college_year[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -5):

the shortest and simplest way is.

```
arrayHere = ['cat1', 'dog2', 'bat3']; 

if(arrayHere[any key want to search])   
   console.log("yes found in array");
```

Comment: can you please share some code, i will check and let you know about it.
it should work.

i am already doing it

Comment: @RyanArief can you please share some code , I will let you know why its not working.

Comment: var arrayHere = ['cat1', 'dog2', 'bat3']; 

if(arrayHere[0])   
   alert("yes found in array");
   
if(arrayHere[3])   
   alert("yes found second in array");

Comment: on the line "if(arrayHere[any key want to search])", you should add some "/' or js would see it as variable.we never know programmer level who search this topic so pls specify more detail on your code.