# check if a string exist in a div text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var qtr = $('div').text();
var qtr1 = qtr.split(',')
console.log(qtr1.length)

for (var i = 0; i < qtr1.length; i++) {
  console.log(qtr1[i]);
}
console.log(qtr1);
if ($.inArray('1st qtr', qtr1)) {
  alert('1st');
}
if ($.inArray('2nd qtr', qtr1)) {
  alert('2nd');
}
if ($.inArray('3rd qtr', qtr1)) {
  alert('3rd');
}
if ($.inArray('4th qtr', qtr1)) {
  alert('4th');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1st qtr,2nd qtr,3rd qtr,4th qtr,</div>
```

I have a div with text in it i want to check if a specific text is in the div. I tried splitting the div text and getting checking `$.inArray` but the first text is not being shown even if it is missing.

Problem:

1. Why do i get 5 as length in even if there are only 4 text. An extra space is being added at the last
2. Why is the first text which is `1st qtr` not shown even if it is existing.
3. What is the best to `check if a text is existing in a text`.

Comment: if you want to highlight keywords you can use https://github.com/julmot/jmHighlight

Comment: @julmot i dont want to hightlight text i will use it as parameter for other purposes.

Comment: you have a comma at the end of text. that's the reason length is 5

Comment: You get 5 as length, because the content ends in a comma - the empty string aftert that is counted as fifth element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do i get 5 as length in even if there are only 4 text. An extra space is being added at the last

The string contains `,` at the end. When the string is split using `,`, an empty string is added as the last element since there is nothing after the last `,`. You can remove the last `,` by using regex.

> Why is the first text which is 1st qtr now shown even if it is existing.

The `inArray` returns the index of the sub-string found in the string. So, for the first string the index `0` is returned. As `0` is falsy value, the if condition is evaluate to false and the block is not executed.

**Updated Code**

```js
var qtr = $('div').text().replace(/,$/, '');
var qtr1 = qtr.split(',');

console.log(qtr1.length)

if ($.inArray('1st qtr', qtr1) !== -1) {
  alert('1st');
}
if ($.inArray('2nd qtr', qtr1) !== -1) {
  alert('2nd');
}
if ($.inArray('3rd qtr', qtr1) !== -1) {
  alert('3rd');
}
if ($.inArray('4th qtr', qtr1) !== -1) {
  alert('4th');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1st qtr,2nd qtr,3rd qtr,4th qtr,</div>
```

> What is the best to check if a text is existing in a text.

`indexOf` is the best to check if the string contains a substring

```js
var str = '1st qtr,2nd qtr,3rd qtr,4th qtr,';

var contains = str.indexOf('4th qtr') > -1;

alert('str contains  4th qtr? ' + contains);
```

Comment: why add -1 at the condition? also 4th is not shown even if it is present i need to show all text since all are present

Comment: what you did is change the last `,` to `space` and did same thing except added `!== -1` in the condition?i want to understand what you did please bear with me.

Comment: @Pekka **1.** Removed the last comma from the string. **2.** Split the string by `,` **3.** The inArray returns the index of the sub-string found in the string. So, for the first string the index 0 is returned. As 0 is falsy value, the if condition is evaluate to false and the block is not executed.

Comment: i see last question this one i really didn't understand id the index is returned as `0` why is it adding `!== -1` will get the first index?

Comment: give me 3 minutes to tick it as answer.please explain last question thank you

Comment: @Pekka The index of the first character is zero, just like array and when the element is not found in the array `-1` is returned, I hope this will clear the confusion.

Comment: @Pekka For reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right