# How to using jQuery to check input value contain value with in the array?

Tags: jquery, json

I got a website need to check user input value is contain porn site URL or not, so I can do reject the input

Using: `Chrome`

```
$porn = [''];
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/aredo/porn-site-list/master/sites.json',function(data){
  $(data).each(function(index,value){
    $pornlist = value.host;
    $porn.push($pornlist);
  });

$('.urlinput').on('input',function(){
  $text = $(this).val();

  if (jQuery.inArray($porn,$text) != -1) {
    //Porn site not allow
    console.log('in webiste')
  } else {

    //Not porn site allow
      console.log('not in website')
  }

  });

});
```

Comment: If you don't need <IE9 support, Array.prototype.indexOf works fine as well.

Comment: if you just do a loop..

Comment: I'm using Chrome,but still not working

Comment: I try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right before,but still not working

Comment: Also, just personal opinion, these are not jQuery objects, so prefixing the variables with '$' is unnecessary.

Comment: @Felix. What's the problem exactly? Does it print anything on the console?

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.inArray($text, $site) >-1` is the key. When no match found -1 will be returned instead of the index.

Demo: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/aZJPgV

```
$site = ['google','facebook','twitter'];

//$('.urlinput').on('input',function(){
  //$text = $(this).val();
  $text = 'facebook';

  if (jQuery.inArray($text, $site) >-1) {
    console.log('in webiste')
  }else {
    console.log('not in website')
  }

// });
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with php?

Comment: An explanation of the problem helps to educate the user too,

Comment: @Felix, maybe jQuery is missing from that page then? It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$site = ['google','facebook','twitter'];
$text = 'facesbook';
if (jQuery.inArray($text, $site)  !== -1 ) {
    console.log('in webiste')
}else {
    console.log('not in website')
}
```

Comment: An explanation of the problem helps to educate the user too,

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is comparing the result to `true`. `$.inArray` (as with `indexOf`) returns an integer value. `-1` if the element is not found and it's index in the array if it is found. Therefore your logic would return `true` when `-1` or `> 0` and `false` if the element is found at index `0`.

To fix this, compare to `-1` instead:

```
if (jQuery.inArray($text, $site) != -1) {
    console.log('in webiste')
} else {
    console.log('not in website')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.inArray($string, $array)`  returns the index of the element in the array,  if it exists in the array. If the element was not found, -1 will be returned

```js
$site = ['google', 'facebook', 'twitter'];
$text = 'facebook';
if ($.inArray($text, $site) !== -1) {
  console.log('in webiste')
} else {
  $.log('not in website')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the loop and test the value

```
for ( var i = 0; i < $site.length; i++){
 if ( $site[i] == $text) {
    console.log('in webiste')
  }else {
    console.log('not in website')
  }
}
```