# jQuery inArray won't find matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array converted from string using JSON.parse:

```
 list = "625, 632";    
 list = JSON.parse("["+items_string+"]");
```

which contains:

```
 Array [ 625, 632 ]
```

Trying to find a given item in the array JQuery inArray will always return -1

```
 if(jQuery.inArray('625', list) > -1){
     //never get here
 }

 console.log(jQuery.inArray('625', list));
 //will print -1
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.inArray(), how to use it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right)

Comment: Documentation says 'The comparison between values is strict'. Maybe searching for a number will yield the expected result.

Comment: console.log(jQuery.inArray(625, list)); try to find int, not string

Comment: You are comparing a string to a number, that's why you get always `-1`.

Comment: @Alfabravo I've read that question before, I know inArray is search for the index, and won't output a boolean, still I didn't know what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a number instead of a string

```
$.inArray(625, [ 625, 632 ]) // `0`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new Array(625, 632);
if( $.inArray(625, list) !== -1 ) {    
    alert("found");
}
```