# jQuery inArray returning false when needle exists in haystack

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to check if user code exist in array. But the jQuery code is returning false even when the code exist in array.

```
function isValidCode(code){
  var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  //return ($.inArray(code, arr) > -1);
  return ($.inArray(code, arr) !== -1);
}

function LuckWinner(key){
  if(isValidCode(key)){
    console.log(key+ ": is in array");
  } else {
    console.log(key+" is NOT in array");
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right
follow this url i think this will help you.

Comment: Its working https://jsfiddle.net/cebgge9x/

Comment: @KuldeepMishra i did check the question, but it didn't sove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be working just as expected.

Note that `$.inArray()` will perform a type comparison; I expect you are passing a string. If you *are* testing for a key that is a string, your `isValidCode` function will return false, as your array only contains integer values. You can cast the code to an integer with `parseInt` to avoid this issue:

```
function isValidCode(code){
    var arr = [1, 2, 3];

    return ($.inArray( parseInt( code, 10 ), arr ) !== -1);
}
```

Comment: @PhilipJems Glad to have helped.

Comment: @PhilipJems, if this solved the problem please mark as solved