# Getting new colors randomly with loop

Tags: javascript, do-while

I am trying to randomize colors by generating random number, then applying 
 it to array to get an color array containing font-color and background-color.

At every "skill" I want to have unique color scheme. So each time I loop skill array I loop color array to fetch color scheme. If this color scheme number (which is same as the randomNumber) is already in use I random again. I do this with do/while loop. When color is not found it pushes it to usedColors array and paints the picture.

For some reason I am still getting same colors. I pasted two pictures to the bottom. Console.log image is about usedColors array (the randomly generated numbers)

```
var usedColors = [];
    $.each(knowledges, (i, knowledge) => {                                  
       do {
          var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(colors.length)),
              rColors = colors[r];                

          } while ($.inArray(r, usedColors) == 0);
          usedColors.push(r);

          $("#knowledges div").append(            
              $("<p />").addClass("knowledge").text(knowledge).css({"background-color": rColors[0], "color": rColors[1]})
          );
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't used the jQuery `inArray` function, but the docs say: " If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0." It looks like you are only checking if the value matches the first element. You need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1. [inArray Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Others already give you a possible solution for your problem. An alternative algorithm would be to reshuffle the colors array, and then just use colors[i] to get a random color

Answer (score 0):

`inArray` gives position of the matching element. So compare against -1, to know that element is not present in the usedColors array.

```js
var usedColors = [];

$.each(knowledges, (i, knowledge) => {                                  
   do {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(colors.length)),
          rColors = colors[r];                

      } while ($.inArray(r, usedColors) != -1);
      usedColors.push(r);

      $("#knowledges div").append(            
          $("<p />").addClass("knowledge").text(knowledge).css({"background-color": rColors[0], "color": rColors[1]})
      );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, are you checking if the array is unique? If so, it looks like you may not be using $.inArray correctly.

Put this in your while loop:`$.inArray(r, usedColors) !== -1`

[jQuery.inArray(), how to use it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right)

Answer (score 0):

To generate array of unique numbers from certain interval you can do this.
In your case the range will be `0, arr.length - 1`.

```js
// function that will generate random unique random numbers between start 
// and end, and store already generated numbers in closure
function generateUniqueRandom(start, end) {
  const used = [];

  function generateInner() {
    let r;
    while (!r) {
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start) + 1) + start;
      if (used.includes(r)) {
        r = null;
      } else {
        used.push(r);
      }
    }

    return r;
  }

  return generateInner;
}

const random1 = generateUniqueRandom(0, 20);

const nums1 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  nums1.push(random1());
}

console.log(nums1);

const random2 = generateUniqueRandom(0, 20);

const nums2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  nums2.push(random2());
}

console.log(nums2);
```

But you need to be careful not to generate more numbers that the specified range is, otherwise you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop method has many interactions, I mean your loop is traveling so much that it only ends until you find the random number that is not in the array (`A short performance problem`). An alternative [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/1074519) so that the array elements are random:

```js
function shuffleArray(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

const colors = [["black","green"], ["white","blue"], ["pink","white"]];
let usedColors = shuffleArray(colors);

//You can now do this:

$.each(knowledges, (i, knowledge) => {
    $("#knowledges div").append(            
        $("<p />").addClass("knowledge").text(knowledge).css({"background-color": usedColors[i][0], "color": usedColors[i][1]})
    );
});
```